# Exception handling in powershell when it's invoked from batch script

Tags: powershell, exception

Unfortunately, my host application can't directly execute PowerShell scripts, so I have written a batch script which calls PowerShell script with content

```
@echo off
echo calling upgrade product with argument %2
if [%1] == [] (
    powershell -ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted -command "%~dp0Product1.ps1 "ProductConfig.xml" -verbose; exit $LASTEXITCODE"
) else (
cd %1
powershell -ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted -command "%1\UpgradeProduct.ps1 %2 -verbose; exit $LASTEXITCODE"
)
```

And in my powershell script i have code like

```
$ErrorActionPreference="Stop"
try{
    Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $dest
}catch{
    Write-Warning "Some Error"
}
```

This executes fine when i execute the script from the PowerShell window(if `$source` is not found it will throw a terminating error and prints `Some Error`). But when executed from batch script if `$source` is not found `Copy-Item` throws a non terminating error and continues(Dosen't print `Some Error`).
How can i make the `Copy-Item` to throw a terminating error if `$Source` is not found?

Comment: try to use `return` instead of `exit`

Answer (score 1):

You have nothing that stop in your catch block.
I presume Your Write-Warning is triggered, but code after your block is runned.

You must return something in your catch block, like:

```
$ErrorActionPreference="Stop"
try{
    Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $dest
}catch{
    Write-Warning "Some Error"

    #$LASTEXITCODE is a special variable in powershell
    $LASTEXITCODE = 1
    exit $LASTEXITCODE
}
```

Note $LASTEXITCODE variable, it is a special variable, the equivalent to `%errorlevel%`, that is used by commands like "cmd calls" by PowerShell.

You can test it by using this command in PowerShell:

```
cmd.exe /c exit 5
$LASTEXITCODE
```

I suggest you to first do a check if path exists:

```
try{
    if(Test-Path $source){
        Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $dest -ErrorAction Stop
    }else{
        Write-Warning "$source not found."
            $LASTEXITCODE = 1
                exit $LASTEXITCODE
    }
}catch{
    Write-Error "Exception during copy: $($_)"
        $LASTEXITCODE = 1
        exit $LASTEXITCODE
}
```

Point of interest:
ErrorAction is used at Function level. Set it at script level will include this settings for many commands.
Exception will be thrown only if copy fail for something else: bad ACL, overwrite etc.

Comment: The `Write-Warning` itself not triggered. It's just prints the error message and continues. It' won't print `Some Error`

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have multiple instructions in the try catch block and I don't want to modify all of them and test again. I have even created a PS profile which defaults `$ErrorActionPreference="Stop"`. I think I will modify all instructions to handle errors separately.

Comment: `$ErrorActionPreference="Stop"` is not setted in your script? If you load it inside a profile,  the problem should be that your profile is not loaded by batch.
Try print is value of  `$ErrorActionPreference` before your commands .

Comment: When I print `$ErrorActionPreference` before the cmdlet it shows it's set to `Stop` but still it throws a nonterminating error. When I pass `-ErrorAction Stop` argument then it behaves as expected.
If I just execute the PowerShell script then it works as expected but when I call the script from a batch file it's not throwing terminating errors.